# Why padding is not made collapsible?

Tags: css

[image]

As the above picture when we apply margin between two divs the greater margin will be placed for eg. if first div contains 20px margin and second div contains 10px margin then margin between them would be only 20px. If I apply `padding-bottom: 20px` to the first div and `padding-top: 10px` to the second div it should result in 20px but results in 30px between them.

So, why padding values are not made collapsible?

---

I have the following html markup:

```
<main>
  <article id="one"></article>
  <article id="two"></article>
</main>
```

So, now I'm applying padding values to the article but should be collpased. So, how the article element (padding) is so called inside element?

Comment: Backgrounds of elements are shown in the padding, what would happen when padding collapses? Other than that, the reason is pretty much going to be "because the spec says so".

Comment: Because margins separate elements while padding separates content from  its own container. Apples and oranges.

Comment: Imagine the two divs with paddings and borders on the outside - what happens to the borders when the padding gets collapsed?

Comment: @sevenseacat Oh! thank you for notifying that. but what if I wanted to collapse the padding like imagining with that border. I mean border between them should be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Since paddings are inside of elements, I don't think it would make sense.
Let's imagine the engines start collapsing paddings : how would you distribute the resulting `20px` between your 2 divs?

Comment: Blend them! Or something.